# Facebook API: cannot print out or convert created_time date

Tags: php, json, facebook

I am trying to print out the date of a comment from a post.

I have this json from the response:

```
  "created_time": {
        "date": "2016-12-24 10:55:12.000000",
        "timezone_type": 1,
        "timezone": "+00:00"
    }
```

I tried converting it to datetime by looping through the json and printing the date:

```
$request = $this->fb_request($id, 'comments');

foreach($request["comments"] as $comm) {
        $date = new DateTime($comm["created_time"]["date"]);
        $date = date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
        echo $date;
    }
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Cannot use object of type DateTime as array
```

Comment: The API itself does not return the data in that format. What you have here must have been transformed into something else already. (The error message suggests that you already have a DateTime object at this point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that the "created_time" is already a datetime of sort. I first assumed that its contents where strings.

```
echo $comm["created_time"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```